# Basic question: how to use Transform Median?

Tags: modeling

[image]

So I set the 3d cursor to 0,0,0 and move the object's origin to the 3d cursor.  Then I select an edge and G, X to move, then type -2 into the Z median.  Object snaps to -2....which isn't aligned to the grid (see picture).

Why doesn't specifying a position of -2 move the edge to the grid line, and how do I achieve this?  I can't turn on snapping/increment because it moves 1 unit from where it is, not to the nearest 1 unit grid line.

Comment: Moving selection to -2 units won't make selection stick to place with coordinates -2, 0, 0. Instead it will move selection 2 units from the current position. And if current position was shifted from the grid so that's what will be the result

Comment: Ok....so how do I set an object to -2, 0, 0 then?

Comment: @MrZak I tested this and it does not seem to be the case.  I moved an object to one position, changed its coordinates to -2, 0, 0 and moved it to another position entirely, changed it again to -2, 0, 0 and lo and behold it went to the same place again.  So your claim that "it will move selection 2 units from the current position" is incorrect.

Comment: Transforming in Blender is relatve.  I don't have any idea what you are doing in your case with "I moved an object to one position" as it is **very** important in which mode the transform is taking place, what origin and pivot points are so I can't tell what you base your judgement on; my statement is correct in regard to situation on the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2.79, typing <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> will move your selection **by** 2 units in the Z of world space, <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>2</kbd>, in the Transform Orientation set in the header. Adjustments to the operation can be made in the Tool Region, bottom left in your screen grab.

If the Median location in the top right is set to 'Global' then any entry you make in the X.Y and Z fields will move the median point of your selection **to** that point in World space, while leaving the relative positions of the elements to each other the same as they were.

If the Median location is set to 'Local' then the coordinates displayed are in the space of the object to which the elements belong: scaled, rotated, and measured from the object's origin. Once again, modifications are absolute, in the object's coordinate system. Mostly, that's very intuitive, but if the object (rather than its mesh) has been scaled at some point, then so have its local coordinates.

If an object has been scaled by 2 in Z, then setting the local median Z of a selection to 1 will send the selection to **2** units away from the object's origin in its local Z.

Try applying the scale of your cylinder.